# What is the default delimiter for Hive tables?

Tags: hadoop, hive, delimiter, create-table

If we don't mention any delimiter while creating a table, is there any default delimiter hive takes?

create table logs (ts bigint, line string)
partitioned by (dt String, country String);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default delimiter   `'\001'`  if you havn't set when create a hivetable .

you can change it to  others delimiter .
for example

```
hive> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS student1
    > (sno INT,sname STRING,age INT,sex STRING)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

Comment: @TKHN  had you use Google to find out?

Comment: What is the meaning of `STORED AS TEXTFILE`? Any other file format in hive table?

Comment: `STORED AS TEXTFILE` simply saves the table in plain text format. There are myriad other formats with which tables could be saved; for instance, ORC, Parquet, JSON, Sequence, etc. Check out the [Apache Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/hive/languagemanual+ddl)  for more info. @rosefun