# Hive Table output shows one non existent Null values when Queried

Tags: hive, hiveql

I know similar questions have been asked, but my Select query FOR THE HIVE TABLE returns all the correct columns and one extra NULL column.

I have created a HIVE TABLE and now trying to query it using SELECT

DDL :

Table DDL :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS family (name STRING COMMENT 'Member Name', 
Age INT COMMENT 'Age of the Member', 
floor INT COMMENT 'Residence floor', 
salary float COMMENT 'per month salary', 
birthplace STRING COMMENT 'State of birth', 
education STRING, 
gender STRING )
COMMENT 'basic details of fmaily members'
LOCATION " /user/hive/warehouse/family/MANJREKAR"
TBLPROPERTIES ('creator'='Sarang', 'created_at'='2019-10-06 14:00:00') ;
```

DML :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/Users/tcssig/Documents/Hive/warehouse/Imports' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE family;
```

Data to load

```
A   50  3   90000   Maharshtra  UG  M
B   46  3   40000   Maharshtra  UG  F
C   15  3   0   MP          HS  F
D   24  3   10000   Maharshtra  PG  F
E   85  3   7000    Maharshtra  HS  F
F   28  2   60000   MP          UG  M
G   59  2   60000   Maharshtra  UG  M
H   21  2   0   MP          HS  F
I   28  2   25000   Maharshtra  PHD F
J   32  1   30000   Maharshtra  PG  M
K   26  1   0   MP          UG  F
L   58  1   55000   Maharshtra  UG  F
M   63  1   25000   Maharshtra  UG  M
```

SELECT name, salary from family;

Output :

```
"A",50,3,90000,"Maharshtra","UG","M"    NULL
"B",46,3,40000,"Maharshtra","UG","F"    NULL
"C",15,3,0,"MP","HS","F"    NULL
"D",24,3,10000,"Maharshtra","PG","F"    NULL
"E",85,3,7000,"Maharshtra","HS","F" NULL
"F",28,2,60000,"MP","UG","M"    NULL
"G",59,2,60000,"Maharshtra","UG","M"    NULL
"H",21,2,0,"MP","HS","F"    NULL
"I",28,2,25000,"Maharshtra","PHD","F"   NULL
"J",32,1,30000,"Maharshtra","PG","M"    NULL
"K",26,1,0,"MP","UG","F"    NULL
"L",58,1,55000,"Maharshtra","UG","F"    NULL
"M",63,1,25000,"Maharshtra","UG","M"    NULL
```

How do I get just the selected columns for my query ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears your whole row land into the name field. With all other fields being Null.

As this is the first field, I bet the separator you have in the file, is not what you specify in your code.

---

You seem to have comma separated data, which is not the default for Hive tables.

Look here for an example on the right syntax for declaring the table: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48616635